# angularjs:show div when clicked on text field in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am displaying add/remove text field in angularjs using ng-repeat method

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

 $scope.items = [];

 $scope.addItems = function(){
      $scope.items.push({
          title:null
        });
 }

 $scope.removeItem = function(index){
      $scope.items.splice(index,1)
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index ">
     //dynamic text field
     <input type="text" ng-model="items[$index].title">

     <div class="opt_btn_cls" ng-click="removeItem($index)"></div>

     //show only when click on current textfield
     <div >item details</div>

</div>
 <div class="ans_opt_btn_add" ng-click="addItems();">
```

I would like to display a `div` when click on each textfield and it should be hide when other textfield clicks.

How can i do it??

Answer (score 0):

Using ngfocus

```
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.selected=-1;
    $scope.addItems = function() {
        $scope.items.push({
            title: null
        });
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1)
    }
 })
```

HTML

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index ">
    //dynamic text field
    <input type="text" ng-focus="selected=$index"  ng-blur="selected=-1"  ng-model="items[$index].title">
    <div class="opt_btn_cls" ng-click="removeItem($index)"></div>
    //show only when click on current textfield
     <div ng-if="selected==$index">item details</div>
   </div>
  <div class="ans_opt_btn_add" ng-click="addItems();">
```